# PowerShell Running Remote Comman on a different path

Tags: powershell, path, remoting

I can run remote powershell commands from my local machine to a server in a different domain by doing something like this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName serverName -ScriptBlock {Get-Process} -Credential $credential
```

However this runs in this default directory for some reason - `c:\users\username\documents`

My actual situation is little different. I have got a powershell script (`Test.ps1`) sitting here:

```
C:\Data\Shared\Installation
```

I want to run this script remotely. I tried different things inside the ScriptBlock but it always gives an error. Looks like a syntax issue. For example I tried this:

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName serverName -ScriptBlock {cd "C:\Data\Shared\Installation" ./Test.ps1} -Credential $credential`

but this gives the following error

```
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument './Test.ps1'.
```

Just need some help regarding this. Thanks.

Edit

[image]

Edit 2

Yes thanks for the comment (which has disappeared now) - putting a semi colon after the path works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to run multiple commands in a scriptblock, you need to seperate them using a linebreak OR a semicolon `;`. Try:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName serverName -ScriptBlock {cd "C:\Data\Shared\Installation"; ./Test.ps1} -Credential $credential
```

Or try this (this isn't a good solution if your script works with relative paths):

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName serverName -ScriptBlock {C:\Data\Shared\Installation\Test.ps1} -Credential $credential
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. The first one works but second gives the following error - The term 'C:\Data\Shared\Installation\Test.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Weird :S are you sure the path is correct? does it help if you run it with `{ . c:\data\... }` or `{ & "c:\data\..." }`?